# Resources on All Kinds of Poetry/Verse

Tags: poetry, rhythm

For a previous question, in which I inquired about writing prose with rhythm, I received an answer saying this: that learning to write poetry should help, from strict-verse poetry to abstract free-verse poetry. I had already learned to write iambicly, and a couple times perhaps have written anapesticly, but I've become rusty and want to learn as many meters and forms as I can. So I ask you what resources you can recommend for this, whether books or online articles. Thank you.

Comment: I just want to say, I managed to accomplish a little prose writing with rhythm but seem to have lost the ability. I want to try a different way than imitation this time.